# jquery event for on render an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do all dom manipulations off screen and then make it visible.  Which works, except now I have the situation where I am trying to do it with a form which I want to focus on the first input text upon rendering it on the browser.

Something like: `myForm.prependTo(myDiv).show().find('input:first').focus();`

Problem is that the focus is being called before the form has finished rendering which is causing the lovely error ***'Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus'***

How do other web developers handle the similiar situation of manipulating elements off screen and then making it visible? I wish jQuery had something like
 `myForm.prependTo(myDiv, function() { /* on render code here */ })`

I know one way of doing it is setting a timeout and when it fires I put focus on the input, but I feel like that's not really the cleanest way to do things. I know the iframe has an onload event, so I'm curious if people usually draw their elements in some hidden iframe and listen for its load event to know when the element has finished rendering? If so could you point me to an example of doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're unable to just call `.focus` after the form is shown?

Comment: as I said before, I get the "can't move focus..." error. This is due to the fact that the focus is called while the browser is still rendering the form. Basically the browser's saying 'hey you cant set focus on the element, it's not visible'.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that `myDiv` wasn't being shown until later either.

Comment: What exactly are you doing offscreen?  In case you didn't realize, most DOM manipulations don't happen live as your code runs.  The browser tends to queue up the manipulations and then re-layout the page once when you JS finishes executing.

Comment: Offscreen I add elements to the form. After that I move it to an empty center div and then make it visible (using .show()) and then focus on the first input field. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myForm.prependTo(myDiv).show(function(e){
    $(this).find('input:first').focus();
});​
```

Comment: FYI `.show()` is synchronous so you don't need to use a completion function with it.

Comment: The function itself may be synchronous, but the drawing of the browser must be asynchronous because if it wasn't then I wouldn't be having the issue at hand :)

Comment: What I want to know is how to know when the browser is done rendering. A cheap trick is to user a timer but I don't really think that's the way it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm 7 years late, but I had a similar problem, which I solved by putting the stuff I needed to happen after the render in a ready handler.

I had a restore function that worked, but there was zero or near zero visual feedback that the element had been restored.

I tried emptying the element first. It still worked, but still had zero visual feedback.

`$("#someSelector").empty();
restore();`

Then I discovered ready() happens after the rendering; so I changed it to something like....

`$("#someSelector").empty().ready(function() {
     restore();
});`

Now the restore() doesn't happen until after the empty() action RENDERS. This means my element APPEARS to empty out and then refill (it always did, but now the user can see it happen).

I found this solution somehow a few days ago for a different problem with some vague search that I can't remember. Then I needed it again but couldn't exactly remember what I did. Now my searches included the word "jquery" and "render" and lead me here.

I ended up going thru my code to find out what I did, and I thought it might be a good idea to post it here in case other people stumble on this post and actually need to execute something AFTER rendering happens.

Cheers.